# lua script Error ')' expected (to close '(' at line 31) near '<eof>'

Tags: lua

01.function vehiclecheck (thePlayer)
02.if getElementData (getPedOccupiedVehicle(thePlayer), motor) == false then
03.setVehicleEngineState ( getPedOccupiedVehicle(thePlayer), false )
04.else
05.if getElementHealth < 261 then
06.setVehicleEngineState ( getPedOccupiedVehicle(thePlayer), true )
07.end
08.end
09.bindKey (thePlayer, "x", "down", startcar )
10.end
11.addEventHandler("onVehicleStartEnter", getRootElement, function(vehiclecheck)
12.function startcar ()
13.if getElementData (getPedOccupiedVehicle(thePlayer), motor) == false then
14.if getElementHealth < 261 then
15.setElementData (getPedOccupiedVehicle(thePlayer), motor, true)
16.setVehicleEngineState (getPedOccupiedVehicle(thePlayer), true )
17.end
18.else
19.setElementData (getPedOccupiedVehicle(thePlayer), motor, false)
20.setVehicleEngineState (getPedOccupiedVehicle(thePlayer), false)
21.end
22.function cardamage (loss)
23.if getElementHealth(source) < 260 then
24.setElementHealth(source, 260)
25.end
26.
27.addEventHandler("onVehicleDamage", getRootElement(), displayVehicleLoss)
28.function vehiclecheckexit (thePlayer)
29.unbindKey( thePlayer, "x")
30.end
31.addEventHandler("onVehicleStartEnter", getRootElement, function(vehiclecheckexit)
32.end

Comment: This is a really bad question. Please read error messages carefully. I have no knowledge of lua but I can see from distance that the error message tells you to put a bracket in line 31 where one is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear: you need to add `)` after `end` on line 32, to close `(` on line 31.